# how to crop image on camera in iphone?

Tags: iphone

Hi am using Camera Application. I need to crop image in particular area of image, which has been taken and used by UIImagepicker. I done with adding overlay in camera and croping image. but i got cropped image is not for my Rect size.

Comment: @Rajneesh071I have the same problem, can you suggest me for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the UIImage+ProportionalFill category by Matt Gemmell. This category extends UIImage by cropping/scaling capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

**Croping start from x=0; y=0; and till width=125 and height=128;**

```
UIImage *image =imageView.image;
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 125,128);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], cropRect);
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]]; 
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```